# What to do when a type has implementation that's no longer valid?

Tags: java, oop, implementation, abstraction

**Current Situation..**

I have a `Car` interface:

```
interface Car {
    void startWith(Key key);
    void switchGearTo(GearMode mode);
    //..

    static Car newCar() { // factory
        return new CarImpl();
    }
}
```

(factory exists in separate class, nested to shorten this example)

This interface has an implementation:

```
class CarImpl implements Car {
    private Ignition ignition;
    private GearShift gearShift;

    public void startWith(Key key) {
        // use ignition
    }

    public void switchGearTo(GearMode mode) {
        // use gear shift
    }
}
```

At this point in time, `Car` is specific enough for the application's needs, so this structure is fine. It was created based on the YAGNI principle, since further abstractions weren't needed and our requirements were met.

**The problem..**

The application's requirements have changed, and `Car` is no longer specific enough. We need different types of cars, such as `SportsCar`; another level of abstraction is needed.

The problem is, `Car` already has a direct implementation, when it should now simply be a level of abstraction without an implementation.

I cannot remove the static factory, or it'll break code. But developers should no longer be possible to create instances of `Car`, since it is no longer specific enough for my application's needs.

**My attempted solution..**

It seems the only way to fix such a problem is to do a major redeployment. The philosophy of the application has changed, meaning a "fresh start" is needed, and there is no other way to solve this problem. (I'm really hoping this isn't the case)

I could specify a default car, I'd still need to create a new (descriptive) method for the default car, resulting in 2 methods in the same class doing the exact same thing (telescoped without change). This adds clutter and possible confusion, which doesn't help with scaling.

**My question..**

Is this a problem that could be solved without a major redeployment? If not, how could one structure their code to avoid this problem? Is it possible to account for such a change in requirements while still abiding by YAGNI?

Comment: The semantics of your library have fundamentally changed. Unless there's some notion of a default car that you can create (and thus encode it in the static method), you have no choice but to update your client code to reflect the semantic change

Comment: Anything would possible on your side, but the fact remains that some clients are doing "Car car = Factory.newCar()";  The factory could now return a SportCar, but clients will still refer to it as "car". Anyway, client's did not know about type of cars before, so obviously they would need to update their code now... Unless, I'm mistaken.. Perhaps, you could include an sample of client code that would be broken.

Comment: @OliverCharlseworth So are you saying this an inevitable problem in an application with requirements that may change in the future?

Comment: Also, just to understand.. Let's say you redesign correctly, how would you consider previsouly created Cars ? It comes down to what Oliver said: you need a default car.

Comment: In order for your new system to work, it needs more information, in this case a [Car Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_classification), such as `Economy Car`, `Family Car`, `Sports Car`, ... You have either already provided that information to the factory, which means the factory can be updated to produce the right kind of car without changing clients, or you are introducing a new required property, in which case all clients *must* be updated to supply that new value. Unless your old system treated all cars as Family Cars, in which case the factory can default to that.

Comment: You created a single global factory that each of your car consumers go to, thereby losing your flexibility to provide a variety of cars for different uses. If you had used dependency injection, could have changed your `Car` provider to produce whichever car is necessary for the current situation. For example, the provider could run per request and provide a SportsCar to all logged in premium users and a Moped to everyone else. All the various components driving a Car would not have to change, as long as they can do their job through that interface.

Comment: @VinceEmigh - I'm saying that unless you eschew YAGNI and design your library such that semantic changes can be made in a backward-compatible way, then yes it's inevitable that clients will need to react.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Is it possible to structure my code a way that accounts for this? As in some kind of design engineered to solve this problem. The situation seems to contradict YAGNI, and is making me contemplate avoiding the principle in the future.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Why don't you just throw an exception in that method instead now? If anyone is still using that method, well, they shouldn't be, as it's no longer valid.

Comment: I also might argue that you may not need a sports car interface. The only thing that is different between a sports car and a sedan is the form, not function.

Answer (score 2):

If a **type implementation** is no longer valid, usually a fresh start is recommended and sometimes it's the only solution. If an **interface** has been defined, you can't just stop other classes from implementing it.

Though with your problem, as I got it, changing the **interface hierarchy** can solve it. Since `interface Car` is more abstract now, create less abstract interfaces (`interface SportsCar` etc) extending the `interface Car`. Also, you have `class CarImpl` to implement the less abstract interfaces.

Finally, you can't stop another developer from instantiating `Car` as long as `Car` interface is defined.

Comment: I don't want to stop people from implementing the interface. I want to remove the ability to create an instance of the interface's direct implementation, currently possible through `CarFactory#newCar()`, since it needs to be abstracted further. I'm looking for a design that accounts for the need to abstract further (check out my comment under Cornel Masson's answer)

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a *factory* is to solve problems like these, i.e. not allowing client code to explicitly construct an instance of a specific class. Your factory should now return an instance of a 'default' class (as mentioned by others) which won't be an instance of CarImpl, but something more specialised, e.g. a sedan, or whatever you conceive to be a default car.

Comment: I could choose a "default car", resulting in a naming inconsistency: `newCar()` is not descriptive. I would need to expose a `newSportsCar()` even if `newCar()` returns it, resulting in clutter. Backwards compatibility outweighs code clutter at this extent, but could be excessive when dealing with larger systems. Imagine car subtypes had direct impl (`SportsCarImpl`, `FamilyCarImpl`, 10 other subtypes), and those types were no longer specific enough, requiring further abstraction. Im looking for a design engineered to account for such semantic changes.

Comment: @VinceEmigh - It's not clear what else you expect - either you retain a method semantically analogous to `newCar()` (which has to return *something*) or you don't (in which case you have a back-compat break).  That's basically the space of logical possibilities.

Comment: @OliverCharlseworth I know `newCar` must return something. But it's not a descriptive method anymore, forcing me to not only keep the `newCar` method (which would return something like `FamilyCar`), I'd have to create a new method `newFamilyCar`, resulting in 2 methods in the same class that do the same thing. If this were at a larger scale, it would add quite some clutter. I want to know how I could have structured my code to avoid support this change while avoiding clutter, or if there's possibly a way I could do it now, without excess clutter

Comment: Personally, I would introduce (say) new newFamilyCar and let newCar delegate to it, but then mark newCar as @Deprecated, with an appropriate javadoc comment explaining this.